# Programando com android studio

Tags: java, android

Estou com erro em meu projeto, o erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> ->/ Error:(23, 31) error: ';' expected/

```
package com.example.lorenzo.pulo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        Game game = new Game(this);
        container.addView(game);


    protected void onPause() //aqui aparece esse erro de error: ';' expected   {
        super.onPause();
        game.cancela();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Em "game.cancela();" a palavra game fica em vermelho .

Comment: Sabendo que já criei o método cancela.

Comment: Se colocar  "Game game = new Game (this);  " acima de @Override da erro quando emulado.

Answer (score 3):

Logo de cara é possível ver dois erros no seu código.

O primeiro seria referente ao `}` dentro de `onPause()`, esse `}` deveria estar antes da definição do método para fechar o método anterior, corrigindo essa parte seu código ficaria assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    Game game = new Game(this);
    container.addView(game);
} //A chave fica aqui

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    game.cancela();

    //Não aqui
}
```

Outro erro seria o escopo da variável `game` como ela é criada dentro do método `onCreate()`, só irá existir dentro dele, não é possível acessar ou modificar fora deste método, deverá declara-la em um escopo maior.

O código completo fica assim:

```
package com.example.lorenzo.pulo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Game existe dentro do objeto, não é visível fora dele
    private Game game = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        //Define o valor
        this.game = new Game(this);
        container.addView(game);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Como o game está declarado em um escopo maior, não haverá problemas nessa parte
        this.game.cancela();
    }
}
```

---

**Obs**: Note o `this` na frente da variável, o `this` refere-se a classe atual, seria o mesmo que MainActivity.game, pode escrever sem, mas é útil em casos onde pode haver ambiguidade